# content uri crashes camera on android jelly bean (4.3)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, uri, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a problem while using content uri with android 4.3 jelly bean (API level 18)
and this is the code that I use to open camera on the device and record a video

after done of recording and try to save my video it shows my unfortunately stopped, any solution

Note: my problem line of code in the logcat (line 241) start from this code

```
mVideoURI = data.getData();
```

this is my NullPointerException problem

```
  if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mVideoURI = data.getData();
        MediaMetadataRetriever mb = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mb.setDataSource(mVideoPath);
        Bitmap image = mb.getFrameAtTime();
        if (image != null) {
            messageList.add(new Message(mVideoURI, time, R.drawable.msg_status_gray_waiting, state, msgStatutSend, image));
            updateAdapter();
        }


    }
```

this is my **logcat**

```
04-01 17:57:03.384 16263-16263/com.example.android.task4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.android.task4/com.example.android.task4.Main2ActivityChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3510)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3553)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.android.task4.Main2ActivityChat.onActivityResult(Main2ActivityChat.java:241)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3506)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3553) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You posted way too much code. Ridiculous. Post only relevant code. Moreover you have a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I uploaded the image to describe the problem detected within the logcat (inside the Main2ActivityChat.java), can you check it please @greenapps

Comment: I posted the relevant code too @greenapps

Comment: You should remove all irrelevant code. And all images.

Comment: ok I did that  @greenapps

Comment: You should have left the log of course. The log tells you exactly which line causes the exception. You should tell us which line.

Comment: I'm sorry for that actually I updated my question by adding the note to describe my problem line of code  (line 241) is in the last if statement block of code starts from     mVideoURI = data.getData();  @greenapps

Comment: So `data==null`. You should check that before use and not use `data` if indeed it is null. It is strange that you say `start from` as it is exactly this line. Well if you indicated it right. Meanwhile you googled around for `NullPointerException` and you wonder why not one or othe moderator marked your post as a duplicate? Well i wonder.

Comment: `(second if statement block of code)`. So why are you posting that first if statement? And all that code before it? You should only post relevant code.

Comment: thank you for your patience, Actually, I removed the first (if statement block of code) and I updated my question with the relevant code only, please can you answer how to avoid this NullPointerException, thank you again @greenapps

Comment: You did not confirm that `data` is null. Or is another variable null? Check and report please. You removed to much. You could have kept that onActivityResult function but only the relevant code inside it. Also show the used intent.